# CBCentralManager not calling didDiscoverPeripheral method when iPhone is locked

Tags: ios, iphone, cbcentralmanager, ios-bluetooth, cbperipheralmanager

I am working on an app that scans for a specific peripheral, ones peripheral is found it should send the small amount of data.

App works in the foreground and also in background. I have also add this code in the plist

UIBackgroundModes

    bluetooth-central

When iPhone is locked and peripheral starts advertising, it doesn't call

```
func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager!, didDiscoverPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral!, advertisementData: [NSObject : AnyObject]!, RSSI: NSNumber!) {
```

I have done some research but couldn't find an answer.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Does your app work only as a central?

Comment: @FernandoReynoso yes

Comment: I think It would be useful if you explain a little more the scenario. For example, if the device acting as peripheral was already discovered by the central. In this particular case maybe you aren´t specifying `CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey:YES` as an option in the `func scanForPeripheralsWithServices(_ serviceUUIDs: [CBUUID]?, options options: [String : AnyObject]?)` method.

Comment: @FernandoReynoso Yes central has already discovered the device in the foreground mode. My problem is when screen is locked, i don't get call back from iOS unless i unlock the screen.

According to Apple documentation CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey:YES is ignored in the background.

Comment: You´re right. Then what you need to do is to make the connection yourself. If you need to reconnect to the peripheral try adding the `CBPeripheral` that you discovered into an array eg.`var knownPeripherals = [CBPeripheral]()` so you can reconnect to whichever known peripheral you need (if it´s available, obviously).

Comment: where should i reconnect to the peripheral? didDiscoverPeripheral is called after unlocking the screen.

Comment: Also the `CBCentralManager` has this `func retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers(_ identifiers: [NSUUID]) -> [CBPeripheral]`. But anyway an array of identifiers is needed.

Comment: I am creating a variable
    var usingPeripheral:CBPeripheral!

Do i need an array? i have only on peripheral to connect. 
Thanks

Comment: If the peripheral for any reason disconnects from the central this delegate method is invoked: `optional func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDisconnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, error error: NSError?)` I think you can try to reconnect there. Also check the Apple reference for long performing long-term actions. Here the link: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH7-SW5

Comment: No, you don´t need an array if you are connecting with only one peripheral. Hope it helps!

Comment: What if you simply want to scan for devices of a specific UUID while the device is locked? I have encountered a similar issue but do not need to connect; simply need to detect a peripheral via scanning https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42775327/scan-for-peripherals-when-device-is-locked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the discovered `CBPeripheral` instance.

```
var activePeripheral: CBPeripheral!
```

Or adding it into an array. If you are discovering more than one peripherals.

```
var knownPeripherals = [CBPeripheral]()
```

This way you can reconnect to whichever `CBPeripheral` you need (if it is available, obviously).

This delegate method is invoked when a peripheral is disconnected `optional func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDisconnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, error error: NSError?)`. You can try using it in your benefit by trying to reconnect to your peripheral.

And finally you should check the Apple reference for [performing long-term actions in background](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH7-SW5).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes, but is there a way to continue to scan for new peripherals while the device is locked?

Comment: I think you should go to a different threat. Try this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42775327/scan-for-peripherals-when-device-is-locked?noredirect=1&lq=1 hope it helps!

Comment: I can connect to a peripheral while device is locked because i had already connected to it. iOS wakes up my app and passes me the peripheral